# Elliptic regularity of Dirichlet problem

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a simply connected domain with $C^\infty$ boundary. Consider the following Dirichlet problem
$$\Delta u |_{\Omega}=0  $$ 
$$u|_{\partial\Omega}=f$$
Under what condition on $f$ or perhaps $\partial\Omega$ we have local regularity up to the boundary?Also what are norm estimates for derivatives of $u$? Can you refer me to a right place to study the regularity matter of PDEs?

Comment: Gilbarg-Trudinger maybe?

Comment: Define regularity: $L^2$, Continuous, more than just continuous?

Comment: at very least $C^\infty$